# unable to understand error in nested list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    z = int(input())
    n = int(input())

    print[[i, j, k] for i in range( x + 1) for j in range( y + 1) for k in range( z + 1) if( i + j + k ) != n ]
```

The above code shows Syntax Error: invalid syntax
please help me understanding the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis for `print`. Call it like so: `print(...)`.